# Python Mogo ImportError: cannot import name Connection

Tags: python, mongodb

Can't figure out why this is not working.

`mogo==0.2.4`

```
File "/Users/Sam/Envs/AdiosScraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mogo/connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pymongo import Connection as PyConnection
ImportError: cannot import name Connection
```

Answer (score 22):

i had same problem and too many files had the import, so, i couldn't risk changing the `import` - (didn't knew exactly where all it is mentioned).

I just downgraded `pymongo`:

```
sudo pip install pymongo==2.7.2
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 16):

Under PyMongo 3.2, you can connect to MongoDB like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
c = MongoClient()
```

[mongo_client – Tools for connecting to MongoDB](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient)

Answer (score 5):

[Mogo Connection](https://github.com/joshmarshall/mogo/#connecting)

```
from mogo import connect as PyConnection
```

`pymongo.Connection` is deprecated use [`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#module-pymongo.mongo_client) instead. In terms of use they are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766754/1587329, here's [the API message](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.6.3/api/pymongo/connection.html) (deprecated at 2.6.3, removed at 3.0):

> **Warning: DEPRECATED:** [`Connection`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.6.3/api/pymongo/connection.html#pymongo.connection.Connection) is deprecated. Please use [`MongoClient`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.6.3/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient) instead.